# Airflow XCom - how to share vars between DAGs using TriggerDagRunOperator?

Tags: python, task, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow

Suppose I have a DAG that does some data processing and the result of this processing is written to the `dest_path` variable.
Is there a way to push this variable to another DAG using `TriggerDagRunOperator`

```
def trigger(context, dag_run_obj):
    dest_path = context['ti'].xcom_pull(task_ids='download_data')
    return str(dest_path)

...
    trigger_next_dag = TriggerDagRunOperator(
        task_id="trigger_next_dag",
        trigger_dag_id="send_mined_data",  # Ensure this equals the dag_id of the DAG to trigger
        provide_context=True,
        python_callable=trigger,
        dag=dag,
    )
```

But this task failes with
`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'run_id'`

The second DAG (`dag_id="send_mined_data"`) supposed to pull this variable in a common way with:

```
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    pulled_string = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='trigger_next_dag')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the source code the TriggerDagRunOperator needs to be extended for your use case. You'll see the [source code here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/dagrun_operator.py#L74:L82).

What you'll need to do is subclass this Operator and extend it by injecting the code of your `trigger` function inside the `execute` method before the call to the `trigger_dag` function call.

Comment: So in triggered tag, how I need to properly pull desired value?
kwargs['ti'] or kwargs['dag_run'] or smth?

Comment: In your execute method you will have a context argument. You pull the `task_instance` from there with `context["ti"]`

Comment: dest_path = context['ti'].xcom_pull(task_ids='download_data') will give me nothing if I'll just paste It into execute() body. I guess it should be passed further in `trigger_dag` call, but how exactly?